# Using same google account on multiple devices

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google-account, apk, multiple-devices

So I have a digital signage application installed on my android tv devices, which I install at various offline stores, which show ads at their stores (remotely configured by me) with my apk (preinstalled from play store). Now this will be across many stores, and I would be using the same gmail account to sign in to play store on those devices. This causes a popup on other devices showing did you login on another device? How to prevent this and solve this problem which I am facing? I doubt even G-Suite allows this.

Comment: Disable *Device Information* after logging into your [My activity](https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity) and see if it fixes